# Tile texture instead of stretch?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, textures

Is there a built in way of drawing a texture in a pattern using instead of just stretching to fill the whole rectangle? I know you can easily do this with a loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, ...);
    }
}
```

but I'm curious if there is a built in function for this since it's probably used very often.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your call to `SpriteBatch.Begin()`, specify one of the wrapping `SamplerStates`.  Then, when you draw a sprite, specify a source rectangle that's larger than the texture.  This will be translated into u/v coordinates greater than 1, which will wrap the texture.